# Test Cases of atof() function in structure format

Tags: c, testing

Two days ago i attended an interview.I had been asked a question and i am still finding answer.**The Question Was tell me the test cases of atof(const char *str) function in c**.I told him various test cases like

1. I have to check the given string should contain only numeric.
2. Given string contain one decimal point.
3. it should not overflow after conversion.
4. string should not be null.

but interviewer was not satisfied and asking for give me the answer in structured format.now my question is how to represent this answer in structure format so that in future i could not make same mistake.

Comment: You want to know all of atof tests from the stdlib right ? And what's a structure format for you ?

Comment: I want to know what is the better representation of answer of the given question because he was not impressed from my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the interviewer means by "structured format", but I would do this by writing down the BNF syntax for floating point numbers (the C language specifies them), and then presenting test cases that test for each path through the syntax. Your cases notably do not cover the sign or exponent, and the number need not contain a decimal point.

A structural approach breaks the problem down into subproblems. Syntax is one subproblem, and the syntax chart or BNF provides a natural way to break that down into subproblems. An additional subproblem is boundary conditions ... there should be test cases for the minimum (> 0) and maximum valid values. There should also be test cases for handling of invalid inputs, but as lundin noted in a comment, that's impossible for `atof` as the behavior for invalid inputs is undefined.

Comment: He told me an example related to this, that let a needle has fall down in floor then how to find it.there are two ways of finding the needle either you will search the whole floor by running or second  you will find in single tile if got then ok otherwise mark it cross so that next time you will not check again and told me now explain the Question.

Comment: @Aalok It sounds like he's asking you to break the problem down into subproblems. What I described does that for the syntax issues. The additional subproblems are invalid (NULL) pointer, and value out of range, which can be broken down into mantissa out of range and exponent out of range.

Comment: i think he was asking me to give answer in subproblems.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can structure your answer by what you are testing, like giving bad formated string (null, empty, etc ...) and by giving bad arguments like bad "numbers" (0 prefix/suffix 2.0, 0.4 etc...) you can also tests negative float numbers, put more than one dot in the string or whatever. I hope i have answer your question, if not, i think i haven't understood the question well.

Answer (score 2):

I understand the term "test cases" differently than you.

I think what he wants are various inputs to `atof` and their expected results. For example:
 1. `atof("1.5")` should return `1.5`.
 2. `atof("-7")` should retutn `-7.0`.
 3. `atof("Hello, world")` should fail. But following Lundin's comment, there's no defined failure behavior for `atof`, so you can't really test this.

The test cases should cover all the different things the function needs to test. But you don't need to write down these things - just the example inputs and expected outputs.

Writing this in a structured format is easy.

Comment: Passing anything but a valid "float number string" to atof() leads to undefined behavior. There is no way you can deterministically "test for undefined behavior". So unless the question was to implement atof(), it would seem that your understanding of test cases is the incorrect one.

Comment: You raise a general problem with testing - you can't test undefined behavior. So for `atof`, the test cases can only include valid inputs. But the concept of test cases in the same.

Comment: Considering how many cases you haven't tested for, perhaps it isn't all that easy. Consider, for instance, test cases for handling the exponent ... a structured methodology would identify that you need test cases for the max and min (but non-zero) values.

Comment: @JimBalter, I wasn't trying to provide the full list of test cases. I just gave some examples to illustrate the idea.

Comment: I was responding to your comment that "Writing this in a structured format is easy" ... it's only easy if it's easy to write the whole list, not just an incomplete one. As I noted in my answer, to completely cover the syntax you need to work through the BNF or syntax chart which, while not hard for floating numbers, is not generally easy.

Answer (score 1):

We used use `atof` in our code most of the time we need to handle `Internationalization/Localization` in many languages `10.0` get converted to `10,0`.

before calling `atof` you need to set locale and after completing the functionality you have to reset the locale.